# How to replace an object's key values if they exist in other object?

Tags: javascript, object

I'm looking for a way to replace object key values if they exist in another object, for example:

```
let objA = {
  x:"1",
  y:"2",
  z:"3"
};

let objB = {
  a:"4",
  z:"newValue",
  c:"6"
};
```

I want to get values from `objB` if the same key exists in `objA`,
result should be something like that:

```
rsultObj = {
  x:"1",
  y:"2",
  z:"newValue"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate the keys of `objA` with `Array.forEach()`, and replace the value of every key that is found in `objB`:

```js
const objA = { x: "1", y: "2", z: "3" };
const objB = { a: "4", z: "newValue", c: "6" };

Object.keys(objA).forEach(key => {
  if (key in objB) {
    objA[key] = objB[key];
  }
});

console.log(objA);
```

Answer (score 2):

This custom `remix` function creates a new object with all the keys of `base` and with values from `extra` if `extra` has them or else from `base`.

```
function remix(base, extra) {
  const result = {};
  const has = {}.hasOwnProperty;
  for (let k in base) {
    if (has.call(extra, k)) { 
      result[k] = extra[k];
    } else if (has.call(base, k)) { 
      result[k] = base[k];
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

You can use the function like this.

```
remix({x:1, y:2, z:3}, {a:4, z:"newValue", c:6});
```

It returns a new object like this.

```
{x:1, y:2, z:"newValue"}
```

Comment: This is perfect, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In single line you can write :

```
Object.keys(objA).filter(key => key in objB).forEach(key => objA[key] = objB[key]);
```